# Visual Studio 2017, SDK

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, sdk

[image: Скрин]

Ребят, подскажите как решить проблему, в настройках лазил, так и не нашел как норм подключить SDK, и что вообще делать

Comment: Вероятно, нужно было при создании консольного приложения поставить галочку `пустой проект`. (но это не точно)

Comment: аа.. этой галочки нет

Comment: Тогда, возможно, стоит выбрать `Empty project` в [этой](https://userdeck-api.s3.amazonaws.com/files/QXOsa7E54Zegqfxp-C%252B%252B-Tutorial%252C-New-Project-Dialog.png) менюшке

Comment: Опишите проблему **текстом**, картинка лишь добавка. По ней нельзя будет найти этот вопрос поисковиком.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно перезапустить установщик VS2017 и в компонентах выбрать `Windows 8.1 SDK`.
[image: MSB8036]

Comment: Ему точно нужен этот Windows 8.1 SDK? Мне кажется, он хочет hello world написать...

Comment: @diraria там номер ошибки внизу. Гугл (и английский stackoverflow) говорит, что лечится как-то так.

Comment: Ок, я не сильно в этом разбираюсь)

Comment: у меня 10 винда, я просто хз как откомпилить нормально, не нашел как сдк поменять на 10й